# Simple rewrite Rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, expressionengine

I'm trying to write this simple rewrite rule that is not working the way i'd like it to. I have this url: http://domain.com/fr/some_city/ that i'd like to rewrite to http://domain.com/fr/properties?city=1234

Here's my rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule   ^some_city$   proprietes?city=1234  [NC,L]
```

In the result page, there's nothing in `$_GET['city']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed ! If it can help anyone else:

As I was looking into PATH_INFO I noticed PHP was running as CGI, so added cgi.fix_pathinfo=0 to php.ini fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression only matches when the path is exact `some_city`, not `fr/some_city`.

You'll either have to add a `RewriteBase` before your rules, but that may cause issues if you have other rules in your htaccess.

```
RewriteBase /fr/
RewriteRule ^some_city$ proprietes?city=1234 [NC,L]
```

The other option is to rewrite the rule to be aware of the language:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/some_city$ /$1/proprietes?city=1234 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply !  I pasted that part of the url, I actually have a /fr and /en folder on the server containing their own .htaccess .  That code is from the .htaccess inside the /fr folder  So I get the properties page correctly, with search results, but since there's nothing in $_GET['city'], I get a result with all cities

Comment: The website is built on ExpressionEngine and I handle the languages with folders containing their own index.php  so /fr has is own index.php and .htaccess and the same goes for /en

Comment: Could you use a debugger, i.e. xdebug, to find the value of the `$_SERVER` variable (specifically, PATH_INFO and QUERY_STRING), and `$_GET`. If you don't have access to a debugger, var_dump debugging could work in a pinch.

Comment: When I do a search on the site, here's the values:
QUERY_STRING = city=1234
PATH_INFO = /proprietes

When I enter the rewrite url:
QUERY_STRING = /proprietes
and there's no PATH_INFO variable

I tested my rule in a temp folder, works like a charm.
domain.com/some_city redirects me to my test.php?city=1234
and values from $_SERVER are correct:
QUERY_STRING = city=1234

ExpressionEngine has something to do with this..